# How to reset rebase squash?

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-squash

How do I reset git squash?

I am using PhpStorm. I squashed commits from last 14 days of work. The commit "HEAD DEV Refactor gulp file" has 50+ squashed commits inside.

How do I show / unsquash them again?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no "unsquashing" in Git normally. I am not familiar with your tool, so my answer applies for the Git command line. If you're on Windows, you probably have Git bash installed, and the tool may have a direct way of launching the Git commandline.

Make a backup of your state to prevent getting into worse trouble:

```
git tag unsquash-backup
```

First check if `ORIG_HEAD` is set to something you like. This should be the last state you had before a rebase.

```
git show ORIG_HEAD
```

If you see that it is the state you want to go back to, just do

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
git rebase --abort
```

If `ORIG_HEAD` is no longer what you want, you should use `git reflog`, which is the usual way of getting yourself out of trouble in Git if you've done something you shouldn't have.

```
git reflog
```

Then look for an old commit (which will look something like `HEAD@{8}`) in the list. That should be the state you want to go back to. Check that commit's history first to be sure by

```
git log HEAD@{8}
```

And then you can reset your branch to that state.

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{8}
```

Of course substituting `HEAD@{8}` everywhere with the commit you found in `git reflog`.

**Note:** standard warning applies, if you use `git reset --hard`, you lose any current uncommitted changes.

Comment: Wow :) but git reflog only shows HEAD@ up to HEAD@{41} when I look at the commits I need HEAD@{49} is it possible to show more?

Comment: How far back the reflog goes cannot be said for certain, it's sometimes cleaned up by Git. `git reflog` shows everything, so if you scrolled all the way down and only saw up to 41, then that's it. You could also try `git fsck --unreachable` to see if it finds your commit. Did you try with ORIG_HEAD first? It should work if you haven't done anything after your squash.

Comment: git origin head shows the squashed commit. I will try that first.

Comment: `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` didn't do anything

Comment: I probably did it. Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer in an hour hopefully.

Comment: If something worked for you, please specify what in a comment or an edit to your question.

Comment: I will edit my answer when I am done fixing my mistakes. `git reflog` worked I just also learned tons of new things about GIT which is great.

Comment: great tip with `reflog` and using HEAD@{#number}, it saved my life :)